# How to multiply a set of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and a list as follows.

```
cols = ['n1', 'n2']

item n1 n2 n3
item1 1 2  5
item2 2 3  3
item3 1  1  1
```

I want to multiply the selected columns in `cols` and add it as a seperate column in the dataframe. i.e.,

```
item n1 n2 n3 multiplication
item1 1 2  5        2
item2 2 3  3        6
item3 1  1  1       1
```

I tried to do this using `multiply` function as follows.
`df[n1].multiply(df[n2])`

However, this is easy when there is only 2 `columns`. Suppose, I have many columns in `cols` list (e.g., `cols = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5']`). How to do such multiplications efficiently in pandas? maybe using one line of code.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cumprod` method on the columns you want to multiply then take the last column you multiplied

```
colsToMultiply = ['n1','n2', 'n3']
df['multiplication'] = df[colsToMultiply].cumprod(axis=1)[colsToMultiply[-1]]
```

You might also want to fill `NaN` with 1 before doing the above:

```
df[colsToMultiply] = df[colsToMultiply].fillna(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

use **prod**

```
cols = ['n1','n2', 'n3']
df['multiplication'] = df[cols].prod(axis=1)
```

**prod** provides `product` of values for provided axis.

In this context, `cumprod` is not right choice, because it provides `cumulative product` and then taking `last column` for result which is extra calculation